# Code Jam 2008 "Price Is Wrong" - Explanation

Tags: algorithm

I have been going through Code Jam archives. I am really struggling at the solution of **The Price Is Wrong** of Code Jam 2008

The problem statement is -

You're playing a game in which you try to guess the correct retail price of various products for sale. After guessing the price of each product in a list, you are shown the same list of products sorted by their actual prices, from least to most expensive. (No two products cost the same amount.) Based on this ordering, you are given a single chance to change one or more of your guesses.

Your program should output the smallest set of products such that, if you change your prices for those products, the ordering of your guesses will be consistent with the correct ordering of the product list. The products in the returned set should be listed in alphabetical order. If there are multiple smallest sets, output the set which occurs first lexicographically.

For example, assume these are your initial guesses:

code = $20

jam = $15

foo = $40

bar = $30

google = $60

If the correct ordering is code jam foo bar google, then you would need to change two of your prices in order to match the correct ordering. You might change one guess to read jam = $30 and another guess to read bar = $50, which would match the correct ordering and produce the output set bar jam. However, the output set bar code comes before bar jam lexicographically, and you can match the correct ordering by changing your guesses for these items as well.

Example

```
Input
code jam foo bar google
20 15 40 30 60

Output
Case #1: bar code
```

**I am not asking for exact solution but for, how should I proceed with the problem**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry didn't put the link to the solutions ! Solutions submitted are available for viewing but I am not able to understand them . All solutions have a common approach yet unable to understand. P.S added the link

Comment: Sorry. We're not going to go somewhere else to see what question you're asking, and then go to a different place to see what others have done to solve that problem, and then come back here to explain the approach to you. Questions here must have all relevant content *here, in the question itself*. If the majority of the content is somewhere else, and that other site is unavailable for some reason (off-line, moved, deleted, etc.), your question has zero value for future readers here. See [ask], and then [edit] your question appropriately.

Comment: @KenWhite Sure ! I have edited the question, hope it is okay now ! Thanks !

Comment: I guess there are also the maximal number of products must be given, which is a pretty important information...

Answer (score 1):

Okay after struggling a bit, I got both small & large cases accepted.

---

Before posting my ugly ugly code, here is some brief explanation:

First, based on the problem statement, and the limits of the parameters, it is intuitive to think that the core part of the problem is simply finding ***Longest Increasing Subsequence (LIS)***. It does rely on your experience to figure it out fast though (indeed most cases in competitive programming field).

Think like this, if I can find the set of items which price is forming a LIS, then the **items left** are the smallest set that you need to change.

But you need to fulfil one more requirement, which is I think is the hardest part of this problem, is when there exists multiple smallest set, you have to find the lexicographical smallest one. That is same as saying **find the LIS with lexicographical largest name** (and then we throw them away, the items left is the answer)

---

To do this, there are many ways, but as the limits are so small (N <= 64), you can use basically whatever algorithm (`O(N^4)`? `O(N^5)`? Go ahead!)

My accepted method is to add a stupid twist into the traditional `O(N^2)` dynamic programming for LIS:

**Let `DP(i)` be the LIS in number[0..i] AND number i must be chosen**

Also use an array of `set<string>` to store the optimal set of items'name which can achieve `DP(i)`, we update this array together with the process of doing dynamic programming for finding `DP(i)`

Then after the dynamic programming, simply find the lexicographical largest set of item's name, and exclude them from the original item set. The items left is the answer.

---

Here is my accepted ugly ugly code in C++14, most of the lines is to handle the troublesome I/O stuff, please tell me if it's not clear, I can provide a few example to elaborate more.

```cs
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int T, n, a[70], dp[70], mx=0;
vector<string> name;
set<string> ans, dp2[70];
string s;
char c;

bool compSet(set<string> st1, set<string> st2){ 
    if(st1.size() != st2.size()) return true;
    auto it1 = st1.begin();
    auto it2 = st2.begin();

    for(; it1 != st1.end(); it1++, it2++)
        if((*it1) > (*it2)) return true;
        else if((*it1) < (*it2)) return false;

    return false;
}

int main() {
    cin >> T;
    getchar();
    for(int qwe=1;qwe<=T;qwe++){
        mx=n=0; s=""; ans.clear(); name.clear(); 

        while(c=getchar(), c != '\n'){
            if(c == ' ') n++, name.push_back(s), ans.insert(s),s="";
            else s+=c;
        }
        name.push_back(s); ans.insert(s); s=""; n++;

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) cin >> a[i];
        getchar();

        for(int i=0 ;i<n;i++)
            dp[i] = 1, dp2[i].clear(), dp2[i].insert(name[i]);


        for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<i;j++){
                if(a[j] < a[i] && dp[j]+1 >= dp[i]){
                    dp[i] = dp[j]+1;
                    set<string> tmp = dp2[j];
                    tmp.insert(name[i]);

                    if(compSet(tmp, dp2[i])) dp2[i] = tmp;
                } 
            }
            mx = max(mx, dp[i]);
        }

        set<string> tmp;

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            if(dp[i] == mx) if(compSet(dp2[i], tmp)) tmp = dp2[i];
        }

        for(auto x : tmp)
            ans.erase(x);

        printf("Case #%d: ", qwe);

        for(auto it = ans.begin(); it!=ans.end(); ){
            cout << *it;
            if(++it!= ans.end()) cout << ' ';
            else cout << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well based on the problem you have specified, if i tell you that you don't need to tell me the order or name of the products, rather you just need to tell me -
 The **number of** the product values that **will change**.
What would your answer be?

Basically then the problem has reduced to the following statement -

*You are given a list of numbers and you want to make some changes to the list such that the numbers are now in increasing order. But you want your changes made to the individual elements of the list to be minimum.*

How would you solve this?

If you find out the **Longest Increasing Sub-sequence** in the list of numbers you have, then you just need to *subtract* the *length of the list* from that *LIS* value.

Why you ask?

Well because if you want the number of changes made to the list to be minimum then if i leave the longest increasing sub-sequence as it is and change the other values i will definitely get the most optimal answer.

Let's take your example -

We have -  `2 10 4 6 8`

How many changes would be made to this list?

The longest increasing subsequence length is - `4`.
So if we leave 4 item values as they are and change the other remaining values then we would only have to change `5`(list length) - `4` = `1` values.

Now addressing your original problem, you need to print the product names. Well if you exclude the elements present in the LIS you should get your answer.
But wait!
What happens when you have many subsequences with the same LIS length? How will you choose the lexicographically smallest answer?

Well why don't you think about it in terms of LIS itself. This should be good enough to get you started right?